# Running a python Facial recog script in the background continously

Tags: python

I created a python script which recognises my face and if it recongnises an intuder it will lock the workstation and If my face is recognised all is well. The main problem I have is that I need to rerun the script every time the code runs. So basiclly I want to make it so its being run continously on my computer even when im not sitting down and even when the screen is locked (Screensaver).
Since all I want to do is use this on my computer localy there is no point in doing it on a server.

What would be the best way to implement this ?

Most posts and aricles I find online just say `while True:` But that doesnt really do anything for me. Since I dont know wether the script will work even when the screen is turned off. and I already know how to use infinite loops.

```
videoCamera = cv.VideoCapture(0)

countRight = 0
countWrong = 0

timeNow = datetime.datetime.now()
timeNow = timeNow.second

while(True):

    timeNowAux = datetime.datetime.now()
    timeNowAux = timeNowAux.second
    if(timeNowAux > timeNow + 8):
        videoCamera.release()
        cv.destroyAllWindows()
        ctypes.windll.user32.LockWorkStation()
        sys.exit()

    ret, image = videoCamera.read()
    imageGray = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = FaceDetector.detectMultiScale(imageGray, 1.3, 5)

    for(x, y, width, height) in faces:

        cv.rectangle(image, (x-20, y-20), (x+width+20, y+height+20), (0,0,0), 4)
        Id, confidence = FaceRecognizer.predict(imageGray[y:y+height, x:x+width])

        if(confidence>80):
            print("Intruder! " + str(countWrong))
            cv.rectangle(image, (x-20, y-20), (x+width+20, y+height+20), (0,0,255), 4)
            cv.putText(image, "Intruder!", (x,y-40), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0,0,255), 2)
            countWrong += 1
        else:
            print("Verified user. " + str(countRight))
            cv.rectangle(image, (x-20, y-20), (x+width+20, y+height+20), (0,255,0), 4)
            cv.putText(image, "Verified user. ID: " + str(Id), (x,y-40), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0,255,0), 2)
            countRight += 1

        # LOCK IF INTRUDER #
        if(countWrong == 5):
            print("LOCKING WORKSTATION!")
            videoCamera.release()
            cv.destroyAllWindows()
            ctypes.windll.user32.LockWorkStation()
            sys.exit()
        if(countRight == 10):
            print("Welcome!")
            videoCamera.release()
            cv.destroyAllWindows()
            sys.exit()

    cv.imshow("Webcam", image)

    if cv.waitKey(100) & 0xFF == 27:
        break

videoCamera.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is the code for reference. I have if check in place for all faces detected, The only thing I can do is remove the sys.exit() parts and keep it running like that.

EDIT::: I created a batch file which will run the script every time the pc is unlocked. And I am getting this error

[The script runs fine while running it with spyder3 however it fails to import cv and numpy when running via TASK SCHEDULER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYeO2.png)

Comment: *"Since I dont know wether the script will work even when the screen is turned off."*.. Have you tried? You need to define some conditions that need to be in place for the check. Like per loop check if there is a face. If no face is present then lock the system. If face is present then check if correct person. With some conditions like that it should work at all times. You should probably also add a time delay. Running your code in a WHILE alone may be heavy on the cpu. All that said we cannot really do much to help you without a code example to test and review.

Comment: @Mike-SMT No it does not work. The code gives an error if I remove the sys.exit() parts and it get tot he part of the code that locks the workstation.